# Ubuntu Squid config example

Tags: ubuntu, squid

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 amd64 and have just installed the Squid 3.1.19 Ubuntu package.

From the [Squid Configuring Page](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ConfiguringSquid), I find that the default config for Squid 3.1 is :

```
http_port 3128

refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320

acl manager url_regex -i ^cache_object:// +i ^https?://[^/]+/squid-internal-mgr/

acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32 ::1

acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8     # RFC 1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12  # RFC 1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16 # RFC 1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src fc00::/7       # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10      # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localhost
http_access allow localnet
http_access deny all
```

My Ubuntu 12.04 server and a WinXP personal computer are sit behind a home router (using the network 192.168.1.0/24) which connects to the Internet. I have also setup a remote computer to connect to the Ubuntu 12.04 server through VPN using the network 10.0.0.0/8.

As a newbie in using Squid, I want to know how to make changes to the Squid 3.1 default config file so that the VPN remote computer (i.e. 10.0.0.0/8 network) could browse the Internet through the Squid http proxy installed in the Ubuntu 12.04 server. Or has the default Squid configuration handled this for me and I do not have to make any change ? Moreover, in the home router, do I need further setup other than redirecting TCP/UDP port 3128 (the default Squid proxy port) traffic to the Ubuntu server through NAT ?

In the VPN remote computer, I am using Firefox. If my Ubuntu server has a network address of 10.0.0.3/8 in the VPN network, should I just fill in "HTTP proxy"=10.0.0.3 and "Port"=3128 in the "Manual proxy configuration" section of the firefox preferences?